# Setting a TextBox's .Text to "" or String.Empty does not show up in the GUI. Do I have to force a GUI update?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Code is running on main thread. 
Code is:

```
OutputBox.Text = String.Empty; //have tried ""
var auto = new AutoGram(PrefixBox.Text, (int)SeedNum.Value, 
     CharsBox.Text.ToCharArray(), SuffixBox.Text); //Just something for my program.
OutputBox.Text = auto.Execute(); //Again shouldn't be relevant.
```

This code runs on click of a "Run" button. I want the outputbox to be cleared upon this button's click and then filled in when the code executes.
I have placed breakpoints everywhere and the text setting does show up as edited in visual studio, but not in the application's GUI. Thanks so much.

Comment: `string.Empty == ""`

Comment: so what did you or do you expect to see..? I would suggest you read up on the refresher free online tutorial `C# Basics Tutorial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider:

1. if `auto.Execute()` takes 'forever' to complete, then you may want to have an `Application.DoEvents()` statement after you set the output box text to `string.Empty` to allow the OS an opportunity to update the GUI while your code is executing. You may also want to consider running the function in a backgroundWorker.
2. Set the return value from `auto.Execute()` to a string variable, then put a breakpoint when you assign the string variable to the OutputBox to evaluate the string when it is returned.  There are sequences that can exist that will cause the string to not display.  One example would be `"\0whatever"`

For example:

```
string foo = "whatever";
string bar = "\0whatever";
OutputBox.Text = foo;  \\\\ displays whatever
OutputBox.Text = bar;  \\\\ displays nothing.
```

This is because `\0` is being interpreted as end of string.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning an empty string to the output and immediately overwriting the empty string by using auto.Execute().

An alternative approach would be to have two buttons, one specifically to clear all fields, and one to execute your method.

```
string output = "foo";

private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = output;
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case too, but auto.Execute() takes forever to complete, and in the breakpoint where the outputbox.text is "", the gui hasn't updated.

Comment: "auto" should be a string too. By using var you're allowing the compiler to infer the type. You should be converting the integers and arrays to strings, as the .Text property requires you to pass in a string.